# How to edit hour and min cell in JFoenix time picker

Tags: css, javafx, jfoenix

Currently the color for the hour cell and min cell in my jfoenix time-picker is black. I would like to add a pointer and a different color whenever I hover over the two. Below you may see an image depicting the two. Would anybody know the css solution to this?

Current documentation: https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/resources/css/controls/jfx-time-picker.css

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the css/html structure is, you're probably going to need something like this:

```
.time:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I found the documentation here: https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/resources/css/controls/jfx-time-picker.css but I can't seem to find the correct one pertaining to the ones I need. I think its incomplete

Comment: Right click the time and use inspect element to find what class is being used to style the numbers

Comment: I am using scenebuilder. They have a show css analyzer but I can't see the popup for date picker unless I preview the program. I wish it was as convenient as a web browser hehe.